# Find parametric UV derivative?

Tags: graphics

How do I find the parametric UV and du and dv of a primitive on a sphere ? Assuming that is all the information you have on the sphere. I want to find the partial derivatives for a primitive if I the only value I supply is either X,Y,Z ?

Comment: There are many different parametrizations of a sphere that we might use in a game. How is your sphere unwrapped? Or, to attack this from another direction, what are you using this for? The more context you give us, the better we can focus on answers that work well for that context.

Comment: The sphere is not unwrapped, if that information helps ? I just want to return a value of the derivative of either the X,Y,Z for the parametric UV.  Where I'm stuck is if the function asks for a primitive how do find the UV and du / dv of that primitive ?

Comment: A uv coordinate requires an unwrapping. That's what a uv coordinate *is* - a point on the "skin" of the surface after it's been peeled open and squished flat into the plane. This unwrapping can be defined in math functions rather than in vertex texture coordinates, but we still need a definition somewhere. To give you a parametric uv and its derivatives, we need to know what unwrapping / what parametrization of the sphere you're using.

Comment: To get the derivative, there must be UV's. I was thinking otherwise that you could get the derivative with just parametric uvs. Once there is a uv coordinate I only need to give it a point in uv space ?

Comment: Let me put it to you this way: how would you define "parametric UVs" in this case? Do you have a specific parametric equation in mind?

Comment: When the mesh, in this case a sphere; has UV.  And I want to find the derivative to which I need to give a value for X,Y,Z; I don't want to guess that value, I want to know specifically the value I need for the X,Y,Z coordinate on the sphere to get the derivative.

Comment: If "parametric UVs" means it "has UV", then you're going to have to provide those UV coordinates of the vertices as one of the inputs. If you want the X Y Z position to be the only input, then you must specify the rule we should use to assign UVs (effectively choosing a map projection). I'm putting this question on hold until you edit it to include the necessary details. If you struggle to find the right projection, try editing your question to describe the game feature you're using this to support — we might be able to guess a suitable UV unwrapping based on your use case.